# ComboBoxSelectedItem me arroja null

Tags: c#, windows-forms

¡hola gente!, estoy haciendo un visor de imágenes. los nombres de mis archivos de imágenes los cargo en un ComboBox en el Load del formulario y los paso a un PictureBox en el evento SelectedIndexChange del ComboBox. todo bien ahí hasta que agregué un ToolStripStatusLabel para ir mostrando la ruta de mi archivo; (lo único que cambia es el nombre cuando paso la imagen, porque están todas en el mismo directorio) o bueno, esa es la idea porque se me ocurrió hacerlo de esta forma:

```
         private void BarradeRuta_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
              BarradeRuta.Text = Path.Combine(@"mi ruta....", 
                                                         ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
         }
```

pero al momento de Iniciar la aplicación con el debugger, me arroja un error dictando que el ComboBox está arrojando null.

espero puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Me parece que falta información para poder dar una respuesta. Asumiendo por el nombre que `BarradeRuta` es el `ToolStripStatusLabel` cual es la intención de utilizar el evento `LocationChanged`. Se supone que `ToolStripStatusLabel ` cambie su valor en un evento del ComboBox

Comment: si, **BarradeRuta** es el **ToolStripStatusLabel**, utilicé ese evento porque me guie en la descripción que dice, toma lugar cuando **ToolStripItem** se actualiza y relacioné "actualiza" con el item cambiante en el **ComboBox**

Comment: El evento `LocationChange` de cualquier control ocurre cuando sus coordenadas de ubicación (Location) cambian. Definitivamente es el evento incorrecto. Intenta ese código desde el evento `SelectedIndexChange` del ComboBox.

Comment: lo arreglé, cómo te marco como respuesta ? solamente agregué mi línea BarradeRuta = Path... en el SelectedIndexChange

Comment: Ya que mi comentario estuvo acertado, Lo utilicé para redactar una respuesta y no dejar la pregunta abierta. Por si la quieres marcar como aceptada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo por el nombre que `BarradeRuta` es el `ToolStripStatusLabel`, esta debería cambiar su valor en el evento `SelectedIndexChange` del ComboBox.

El evento que estás utilizando `LocationChange` de cualquier control ocurre cuando sus coordenadas de ubicación (Location) cambian.

Intenta ese código desde el evento SelectedIndexChange del ComboBox.